# Ajax error function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Currently I am using `FormAuthentication` to validate user. When it is expired, it will force the user out. So, it supposed will prompt the user with error message in ajax, but it jump over ajax function.

Here is my code:

```
$('#AddSalesTeamForm').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
                    url: "/ABC/AddST/",
                    data: {
                        "Username": $("#username").val(),
                        "FullName": $("#fullName").val()
                    },
                    type: "POST"
                })
                    .success(function (data) {
                        swal({
                            title: "Done!",
                            text: "Successfully added!",
                            type: "success"
                        },
                        function () {
                            window.location.href = '/ABC/Index';
                        });
                    })
                    .error(function (data) {
                        swal("Oops", "We couldn't connect to the server!", "error");
                    });
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

Comment: Where is your code for the server side ? `url: "/ABC/AddST/"`,. Try to console.log data on `success` and/or `error` function to know the error you are getting.

Comment: because you're ajax code syntax itself is not right.

Comment: use @choz's answer. console.log the `success and/ error` data callback to know the response you are getting

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it wrong. `$.ajax` returns a [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jqXHR) object. And it doesn't have methods such as`success` nor `error`. jqXHR only has these following promise methods;

- done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {});
- fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {});
- always(function( data|jqXHR, textStatus, jqXHR|errorThrown ) {
  });
- then(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {}, function(
  jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {});

You might want to do it like,

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/ABC/AddST/",
    data: {
        "Username": $("#username").val(),
        "FullName": $("#fullName").val()
    },
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
        // do something
    },
    error: function(data) {
        swal("Oops", "We couldn't connect to the server!", "error");
    }
})
```